# How to set gradient background color to entire buttomNavigation view rather than item wise?

Tags: android, xml, gradient, android-drawable

Hi I have requirement to use gradient colour for ButtomNavigation view programatically.
I have created a gradient color drawable.It works fine When i set it as background to ButtomNavigation bar like `bottomNavigationView.setItemBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_color_blue));`

it comes like below

[image: gradient item wise]

But I want the color uniformly across the whole `buttomNavigation` bar like the below image

[image: gradient color example]

I tried `bottomNavigationView.setBackground();` , `bottomNavigationView.setBackgroundResource();` etc
but none works. All it came was plain blue not the gradient one.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: use android:background="drawable/yourbg"

Comment: In the Material Components Library the background works only if it si an instance of `ColorDrawable`

Comment: I have to change it programatically. Actually I have three other gradient color.

Comment: `android:background` or `setBackground()` work in the same way. If it is a `ColorDrawable` or a color just fill the shape with that color.

Comment: Can we create gradient color with ColorDrawable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
bottomNavigationView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_color_blue));
bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent); //you may or may not need to do this
```

The reason you got output shown in first picture is because you were using `setItemBackground`. As the name implies it sets background to the items

To set the background of the `bottomNavigationView` you actually need to use `setBackground(Drawable)` which takes in a [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) parameter and not the `INT`. Hence you provide it by calling `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_color_blue)`

Comment: I tried but it is setting the gradient color instead I getting a simple blue color.

Comment: Please show us your `gradient_color_blue.xml` then.
Edit your question and paste it there.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not load the gradient color to the entirety  of ButtomNavigation view.I set angle attribute to 90 of the gradient color xml.

Now even if the color is filled individually for each item it will look uniform.

below is my gradient color xml.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0A4197"
        android:centerColor="#0A4197"
        android:endColor="#0D59CF"
        android:angle="90">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```